# How to loop over a list containing two different pattern files in linux (bash)?

Tags: linux, bash

I got a list containing filenames that match the following two patterns:

- one is like XXX_01.fastq
- another is XXX_01_001.fastq

I am going to write a `for` loop (in bash) to loop over all the filenames with different patterns and I need to determine which ones match the patterns above. Any help about it?

Comment: In which language? What have you done so far?

Comment: in shell scripting. now I have make a list, which contents all the suffix of the file name, e.g. xxx with out the number.

Comment: See the example in my answer with bash pattern matching. I think that is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contents of list.txt:

```
$ cat list.txt
AAA_01.fastq
AA_01_001.fastq
BBB_01_002.fastq
BBB_02.fastq
```

Example using bash pattern matching:

```
for file in `cat list.txt`; do
  if [[ $file =~ [A-Z]{3}_[0-9]{2}\.fastq || $file =~ [A-Z]{3}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{3}\.fastq ]]; then
    echo "MATCH $file";
  fi;
done
```

Output:

```
MATCH: AAA_01.fastq
MATCH: BBB_01_002.fastq
MATCH: BBB_02.fastq
```

Comment: actually in my list I only having names just have like AAA,BBB,AA. So I want to match the different suffix at the end. some of the file have _01.fastq format , some of them have _01_001, _01_002 format